# Pandas to_excel() MemoryError при большом количестве записей

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, список

Имеется до 400 000 записей в списке, каждая из которых представляет собой словарь с 30 параметрами.

При сохранении в Excel такого количество записей у заказчика кидает ошибку `MemoryError`.

Можно ли как нибудь снизить потребление оперативной памяти?

Лог привести не могу, могу только в виде картинки.
Использую:

```
pd.DataFrame(items).to_excel(config["output_filename"], index=False)
```

Возможно я ошибаюсь и это проблема не метода сохранения, а метода превращения в DataFrame.

Log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:/trudvsem.ru/parser_database.py", line 173, in
save_page(products, config["size_save_block"])
File "f:/trudvsem.ru/parser_database.py", line 150, in save_page
append_df_to_excel(config["output_filename"], pd.DataFrame(item))
File "f:/trudvsem.ru/parser_database.py", line 96, in append_df_to_excel
writer.book = load_workbook(filename)
File "C:\Users\Cineofilms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 314, in load_workbook
reader.read()
File "C:\Users\Cineofilms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 279, in read
self.read_worksheets()
File "C:\Users\Cineofilms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 227, in read_worksheets
ws_parser.bind_all()
File "C:\Users\Cineofilms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 426, in bind_all
self.bind_cells()
File "C:\Users\Cineofilms\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 343, in bind_cells
self.ws._cells[(cell['row'], cell['column'])] = c
MemoryError
```

**Метод**

```
def save_page(items, count):
    print("Удаление файла", config["output_filename"])
    try:
        os.remove(config["output_filename"])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print()
    len_list = str(len(items))
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(0, len(items), count):
        chunk = pd.DataFrame(items[i:i + count])
        if(id == 0):
            append_df_to_excel(config["output_filename"], chunk, header=True)
        else:
            append_df_to_excel(config["output_filename"], chunk, header=False)
        cnt += 1
        print("Сохранено", str(cnt * count) + "/" + len_list)
```

**Update**

Переписал под пагинацию database

```
def get_database_page_save():
    index = 0
    while True:
        last_index = index + config["size_save_block"] + 1
        sql = """SELECT * FROM vacancy WHERE id > %s and id < %s"""
        data = (index, last_index)
        print("Запрос вакансий с id c", index, "по", last_index)
        items = core.database_request(config, sql, data)
        print("Данные получены. Количество вакансий", len(items))
        if(len(items) == 0):
            break
        else:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(cpu_count) as executor:
                results =  executor.map(generation_dict, items)
            if(index == 0):
                print("Удаление файла", config["output_filename"])
                try:
                    os.remove(config["output_filename"])
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    print()

                append_df_to_excel(config["output_filename"], pd.DataFrame(results), header=True)
            else:
                append_df_to_excel(config["output_filename"], pd.DataFrame(results), header=False)
        print("Сохранено", str(last_index - 1), "вакансий")
        index = index + config["size_save_block"]

def generation_dict(item):
    temp = {
        "id": item[0],
        "vacancy_id": item[1],
        "region": item[2],
        "company_ogrn": item[3],
        "company_code": item[4],
        "company_hr_agency": item[5],
        "company_phone": item[6],
        "company_inn": item[7],
        "company_name": item[8],
        "company_email": item[9],
        "company_kpp": item[10],
        "company_url": item[11],
        "creation_date": item[12],
        "modify_date": item[13],
        "salary": item[14],
        "salary_min": item[15],
        "salary_max": item[16],
        "job_name": item[17],
        "vac_url": item[18],
        "employment": item[19],
        "schedule": item[20],
        "duty": item[21],
        "specialisation": item[22],
        "count_jobs": item[23],
        "requirement_education": item[24],
        "requirement_qualification": item[25],
        "requirement_experience": item[26],
        "location": item[27],
        "lat": item[28],
        "lng": item[29],
        "term": item[30],
        "currency": item[31]
    }
    return temp
```

**Core**

```
def database_request(config, sql_request, data=None):
    with closing(ps.connect(dbname=config["db_name"], user=config["db_user"], password=config["db_password"], host=config["db_host"])) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            if data is None:
                cursor.execute(sql_request)
                conn.commit()
            else:
                cursor.execute(sql_request, data)
                conn.commit()
            try:
                return cursor.fetchall()
            except:
                return None
```

Сейчас тестирую этот метод. Если добавлять по 10 000, (нужно добавить чуть более 300к), то максимальное потребление ОЗУ составило 4.5GB

Думаю, вообще подход с добавлением по пакетам данных считаю не состоятельным, так как все равно, перед добавлением мы читаем данные из Excel и помещаем в память.

Вот метод, который отвечает за это

```
def load_workbook(filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=KEEP_VBA,
                  data_only=False, keep_links=True):
    """Open the given filename and return the workbook

    :param filename: the path to open or a file-like object
    :type filename: string or a file-like object open in binary mode c.f., :class:`zipfile.ZipFile`

    :param read_only: optimised for reading, content cannot be edited
    :type read_only: bool

    :param keep_vba: preseve vba content (this does NOT mean you can use it)
    :type keep_vba: bool

    :param data_only: controls whether cells with formulae have either the formula (default) or the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet
    :type data_only: bool

    :param keep_links: whether links to external workbooks should be preserved. The default is True
    :type keep_links: bool

    :rtype: :class:`openpyxl.workbook.Workbook`

    .. note::

        When using lazy load, all worksheets will be :class:`openpyxl.worksheet.iter_worksheet.IterableWorksheet`
        and the returned workbook will be read-only.

    """
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
                        data_only, keep_links)
    reader.read()
    return reader.wb
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @MaxU добавил изменения для пагинации из database

Answer (score 4):

Можно читать `items` по частям, создавать небольшие DataFrame'ы и [дописывать их в существующий Excel файл](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046), используя функцию `append_df_to_excel()`:

```
cnt = 0
chunksize = 10**4
for i in range(0, len(items), chunksize):
    chunk = pd.DataFrame(items[i:i + chunksize])
    append_df_to_excel(filename, chunk, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=cnt==0)
    cnt += 1
```

Comment: у заказчика при любом размере chunksize все равно падает эта ошибка. Всего 8 GB RAM на устройстве, но ее походу не хватает

Comment: @danilshik, на какой строке кода возникает ошибка?

Comment: добавил лог. Заказчик говорит, он хоть 5000 ставит, хоть 5, все равно выкидывает ошибку, хотя потребление в любой момент времени не составлял более 2/3 всей ОЗУ

Comment: @danilshik, очевидно не стоит читать `items` (400 000 записей) целиком в память, когда всего 8GiB памяти и неизвестно сколько из них свободной...

Comment: я же написал, что даже создание dataframe по 5 кидает ошибку

Comment: @danilshik, я говорю о списке items, в котором около 400 000 записей и который вы целиком читаете в память, судя по описанию.

Comment: может сделать пагинацию на уровне СУБД?

Comment: @danilshik, я думаю мне стоит подождать еще недельку, чтобы вы раскрыли больше подробностей... ;)

Comment: я просто не могу у себя поймать данную ошибку. Уменьшил используемую ОЗУ ОС с 16 GB до 7 GB, забил вкладками  занятую память до 70%. Запустил скрипт сохранения всего dataframe, у меня сохранился, хоть и потребление доходило до 96%, думаю приложения работающие не на переднем плане выкладывались на SDD. Сейчас тестирую по частям, как у вас. Но думаю она тоже пройдет. А вот у заказчика падает

Comment: @danilshik, а вы сами на машине заказчика исправление ставите или ему даете? А то мало ли и исправление тот так и правильно не поставил :)

Comment: @gil9red, ну а что там сложного, просто заменить его и все.
Вот сейчас тестирую последний метод, и уже вижу, что потребление уже составляет 3.7 GB, а я еще и не закончил. Считаю, что такое потребление, лишь для того, чтобы сгенерировать Excel из SQL, слишком большое. А вариантов не вижу

Comment: @danilshik А заказчик, случайно, не из тех хитрых товарищей, которые отключают своп-файл в винде? )

Comment: @CrazyElf хорошая идея, проверю =)

Comment: @danilshik Дык! Не факт, конечно, но может быть как отключен, так и просто жёстко задан в конкретное значение, которого мало в итоге, всякое бывает )

Comment: @CrazyElf а какой нормальный размер от процентном соотношение от ОЗУ, 100% (если 8 GB ОЗУ, то столько же подкачка)?

Comment: @danilshik Нормальный размер свопа - это вариант "по усмотрению системы", всё остальное - от лукавого )  А так вроде считалось, что нужно двойной размер ОЗУ ставить, но я точно уже и не помню

Answer (score 0):

Заказчик не скинул полностью ошибку

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 37.3 MiB for an array with shape (31, 315204) and data type object.
```

Решение: включить или увеличить размер файла подкачки.

Также нужно убедиться, что Python установлен x64 разрядности

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)